# Yearling badge twice in two days?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I'm not one to hand back accolades, but I'm pretty sure I just earned the "yearling" badge twice in two days. Is that expected behavior?

I'm guessing that it's because I've been here 2+ years, and earned 400 rep as of today, while doing basically nothing the rest of the time?

Comment: I'll let you know when I get the two year milestone, hopefully I'll get two badges.

Answer (score 6):

You've been a member for more than 2 years, but you only yesterday met the reputation requirement to collect the second badge, and only the day before met the reputation requirement to collect the first.  Yearling requires 200 reputation per year; when your rep times years exceeds that, you get the badge when the script next runs.

Congratulations!

Comment: Ah! So that explained why I've gained Yearling 4 times in the last 24 hours oO I wonder if it's possible to get more Yearling badges than the Workplace has been opened for (ie, if it's based on the age of the account or on the age of the site) :D